# Angular2. Почему не работает привязка данных?

Tags: html5, binding, angular2, typescript

Сделал привязку данных, а значение на странице не меняется. Хотя в переменной изменяется.

TS:

```
export class SliderRangeComponent {
    range: string = "25 - 55";

    onRangeChange(model: string): void {
        console.log("range " + this.range);
        this.range = model;
        console.log(model);
    }

    createSliderRange(minValue: number, maxValue: number) {
        var scope = this;

        $("#slider-range").slider({
            animate: "fast",
            range: true,
            min: minValue,
            max: maxValue,
            values: [ minValue, maxValue ],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                let newVal: string = `${ui.values[0]} - ${ui.values[1]}`;

                //$("#range").val(newVal);

                scope.onRangeChange(newVal);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="range">Years range: </label>
    <input type="text" id="range" value="{{ range }}" [ngModel]="range" />{{ range }}
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Если убрать из комментариев это `$("#range").val(newVal);`, то значение меняется. Но как я понял оно должно изменяться при изменении переменной range

Comment: 1. Этот код вообще не очень-то и похож на angular2. 2. То, что он делает - это какая-то жесть. Особенно, сложение строк из jQuery-объектов в возвращаемом значении. 3. [mcve]

Comment: где вызывается `createSliderRange`?

Comment: @Grundy в компоненте родителе

Comment: на самом деле все просто: ангуляр не знает, что что-то поменялось, когда вызывается коллбэк у jquery, поэтому и не обновляет view, так же самая проблема что и была с первым ангуляром. поэтому и не рекомендуется использовать jquery плагины внутри приложений на ангуляре

Comment: @Grundy я просто решил использовать готовую библиотеку, поэтому и используется этот код

Comment: @ViktorBylbas, очевидно надо было искать готовую библиотеку под angular2. Либо тогда уж пользоваться _только_ готовой библиотекой, без всяких ангуляров

Comment: @Grundy, понятно. Спасибо